# Imagemagick Paperclip Error With Uploading JPG Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, ubuntu-18.04

I recently changed my server to Ubuntu 18.04 and now I have an error with paperclip  and imagemagick. File uploads work locally but not on my server. I am running rails 5.2.3 and paperclip 5.2.1 and ImageMagick 7.0.8-56. I added the following line to environments/production.rb:

```
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin/'
```

but still get the error. When I run identify -list format to see what files Imagemagick works with, it does not say jpg, which is different than my old server. Here is the partial output:

```
     ICON* rw-   Microsoft icon
      IIQ  r--   Phase One Raw Image Format
     INFO  -w+   The image format and characteristics
   INLINE* rw+   Base64-encoded inline images
      IPL* rw+   IPL Image Sequence
   ISOBRL* -w-   ISO/TR 11548-1 format
  ISOBRL6* -w-   ISO/TR 11548-1 format 6dot
      JNX* r--   Garmin tile format
     JSON  -w+   The image format and characteristics
        K* rw+   Raw black samples
      K25  r--   Kodak Digital Camera Raw Image Format
      KDC  r--   Kodak Digital Camera Raw Image Format
    LABEL* r--   Image label
```

The error I get is Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in my production log when I upload an image.

Comment: If identify -list format does not find any image delegates, then it was not installed properly or was installed from source. With source installs, one has to install all delegates first. If delegates were installed, then ImageMagick cannot find them where it expects them.

Comment: Makes sense. I believe I installed it from source. Any idea how do I fix the problem? I appreciate your insight.

Comment: Looks similar to https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=36509

Comment: @fmw42 I posted in both places. Thanks for your help. It led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Some files were apparently not installed because I installed imagemagick from source. I had to hard delete the folder with imagemagick in it and reinstall using sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev . Thank you.